# python multiple regular expressions

Tags: python, expression

I need to apply multiple regular expressions on a string which I'm doing like this:

```
regex = re.compile("...")
regex2 = re.compile("...")
regex3 = re.compile("...")
regex4 = re.compile("...")
if regex.match(string) == None and regex2.match(string) == None and regex3.match(string) == None and regex4.match(string) == None:
```

I was wondering if there is another way to somehow merge or combine the single regular expressions or if I'm already doing it the 'right way'?

Comment: well, it would help if you could give sample input/output and what the regex looks like... but essentially you can combine regex expressions into one regex almost all the time. usually using `|` .

Comment: do you want apply different actions dependent on the match?

Comment: e.g. I have two expressions regex1 = re.compile("[0-9]+[a-zA-z0-9]*")
 regex2 = re.compile("[a-zA-z]*[0-9]+[a-zA-z]+[a-zA-z0-9]*"), no the match action should always be the same if the result of a match is not 'None then nothing happens

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
r_list = [re.compile("..."),
          re.compile("..."),
          re.compile("..."), 
          re.compile("...")]
if any(r.match(string) for r in r_list):
    # if at least one of the regex's matches do smth
```